# Send BackboneRelational as ajax data

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-relational

I have a model that extends `Backbone.RelationalModel` and that has a one to many relation, the problem occurs when I try to send an ajax request with that model as the parameter.

```
$.ajax(
        url: 'save'
        type: 'POST'
        data:
          project: MyApp.project
      )
```

I get the following error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_permitsAvailable' of undefined` it occurs in the method named `acquire`
Could anyone tell me why this is happening ?

EDIT:

after digging for the cause of the error, I found that `jQuery.param` function defines `add(key, value)` function, at some point this `value` attribute is `acquire` function, this function will have no this, so I get the error, I don't know why `_queue` of Backbone.RelationalModel gets serialized ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why that is happening. Here's some info that may help you solve the problem, though:

The `acquire` method is part of `Backbone.Semaphore`, which is a mixin that's used for queue and concurrency management within Backbone.Relational. The semaphore mixin is mixed into a few different classes, including the `RelationalModel`.

The private `_permitsAvailable` property only is accessed within the mixin itself, using `this._permitsAvailable`. Your error message tells you that the error occurs, because `this` is undefined. This can only ever happen when a method is executed with `Function.call` or `Function.apply`.

**Edit:** The issue seems to be that jQuery is trying to serialize the model by iterating each of it's properties, and if the property is a function, calling that function and serializing its return value. This is a no-go for Backbone models, because the data attributes aren't actually on the model object, but stored in the `Model.attributes` property.

This problem should be easily fixed by converting the model object to a more serialization-friendly format using the `Model.toJSON` method :

```
$.ajax(
  url: 'save'
  type: 'POST'
  data:
    project: MyApp.project.toJSON()
)
```

Quoting from the [Model.toJSON documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON):

> Return a copy of the model's attributes for JSON stringification. This can be used for persistence, serialization, or for augmentation before being sent to the server. The name of this method is a bit confusing, as it doesn't actually return a JSON string — but I'm afraid that it's the way that the JavaScript API for JSON.stringify works.

You must also make sure that `includeInJSON` option in `reverseRelation` for backbone-relational is set to false to avoid serializing the related models in your `model.attributes`.

Comment: you are right, the function gets called without a context from the `jQuery.param` function, I added some info to the question.

Comment: Thanks I had to remove the models from the attributes as I was using backbone relational, I added this to your answer if you don't mind.